# NextAuth session objects always return null

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

I'm using useSession and getServerSession to get session data. but session object is always returning null.
I expect session object like this ({user {name: "demo_user".....etc} ,{expires: "2023-11-23T02:38:54.547Z"}})
but i only get expires object, I can't get user object. user object is always null.

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth, {NextAuthOptions} from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import {getApi} from "@/utils/httpRequest";
import url from "@/app/api/url";

type ClientType = {
    clientId: string;
    clientSecret: string;
};

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        } as ClientType),

        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: {label: 'email', type: "text"},
                password: {label: 'password', type: 'password'},
                key: {label: 'key', type: 'text'}
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                console.log(credentials)
                if (credentials?.password && !credentials?.key) {
                    const userInfo: any = await getApi(url.getUserAuth)
                    console.log("credentials password -> " + credentials.password)
                    console.log("user password ->  " + userInfo.user.password);

                    if (!userInfo.user || !userInfo?.user.password) {
                        throw new Error('Invalid credentials (No user info)');
                    }

                    const isCorrectPassword = userInfo.user.password === credentials.password ? true : false;
                    console.log("isCorrect ->" + isCorrectPassword)

                    if (!isCorrectPassword) {
                        throw new Error('Invalid credentials(Invalid password)');
                    }
                    return userInfo;
                }

                //use key login
                const userInfo: any = await getApi(url.getUserAuth)
                const isCorrectKey = userInfo.user.key === credentials?.key ? true : false;
                if (!isCorrectKey) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
                }
                console.log(userInfo)
                return userInfo;
            }
        }),
    ],
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    session: {strategy: "jwt"},
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export {handler as GET, handler as POST, authOptions};
```

after login, go to /Home

app/Home/page.tsx

```
"use client"
import EmptyState from "@/components/Sidebar/EmptyState";
import Contents from "../Contents/Contents";
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar/NavBar";
import {useRouter} from 'next/navigation';
import {SessionProvider, useSession} from "next-auth/react";
import {useEffect} from "react";

export default function HomePage() {
    const {data: session, status} = useSession();
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
        // session is null
        console.log("session -> ",session)
        if (status !== 'authenticated') {
            router.push('/Auth')
        }
    }, [status, router]);
    return (
        <SessionProvider>
            <header className="header mb-4 px-sm-2 sticky top-0 z-50 border-bottom">
                <NavBar/>
            </header>
            <section className="body flex-grow-1 px-sm-2 mb-4">
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center py-7">
                    <Contents/>
                </div>
            </section>
        </ SessionProvider>
    );
}
```

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"
export default async function getSession() {
  // session is null
  console.log("session in server",getServerSession(authOptions))
  return await getServerSession(authOptions);
}
```